# Methods and structs in C

Tags: c

I was trying to solve this old lab sheet-
http://csis.bits-pilani.ac.in/faculty/murali/dsa-10/labsheet3_sec4.pdf

So my question is I have to use this method -

`int createMaze(Maze *pm, char *mazefilename)`

This will enter values in the Maze.But since it is not returning the Maze how can I use it in this method-

```
Boolean findCheese(Maze m, int n, int posi, int posj, char
**path_so_far, int past_i, int past_j)
```

Also I cant call `findCheese` method from `createMaze` I have to call both of them from another `driver.c` file.SO is the definitions of the methods wrong or is there someway I can use `Maze` in both the methods?

Comment: In `driver.c` you can have `Maze m;` and have a call `createMaze(&m)` and later call `findCheese` with the updated/initialized `m`

Comment: Hint: pointer parameters *refer* to something outside the function's automatic storage area. This one refers to something that isn't `const`.

Comment: Still the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the document you linked to, it says:

> Create a driver file `maze.c` for meeting the objectives of this problem.
>   This creates the Maze using `createMaze`. It then calls `findCheese` to determine the path.

The code will look something like:

```
Maze m;
createMaze(&m, "some file name");
findCheese(m, ... rest of the arguments ...);
```

Comment: `createMaze` is working but when I try to print the Maze in `findCheese` it is giving garbage values.

Comment: Also when I try to print the Maze in driver.c after calling `createmaze` it is giving garabage values

Comment: @Coder, you should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so others can help you diagnose the problem.